# How to return the form value from view to controller in spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
List<ThresholdService> name = new ArrayList<ThresholdService>();
```

////threshold is a service my POJO class.

model.addAttribute("name", name);

the above is in my controller class. now i want to edit the content on my jsp .

```
  <c:forEach var="val" items="${ser}">
     <div id="value1" contenteditable><c:out value="${val.warningValue}" /></div>
   </c:forEach>
```

on submit i want to update the infoemation of java  threshold object.

Comment: I am a little unclear as to what you are asking, but if what you are asking is how do you take values from the web page and update them in Spring, then simple answer is you add a Model Attribute to your form and as a parameter to your Controller's handler method.  This is sorta Spring MVC 101, and I would suggest reading through the Reference material (which they do an EXCELLENT job of maintaining on the Spring.io site) and working through the tutorials.

Comment: thank you @CodeChimp now i am using form tag and able to update the attributr.